# Installing StarTeam 2006 on Windows Server 2000 or 2008

Tags: starteam

Help, can anyone give me any pointers as too how and install StarTeam 2006 on a windows server.  The installer does not work - pheewww.

If there is anyone out there who has been able to copy the files off one server and get them working on another - i'd be very appreciative of knowing, how to do it, what COM objects need registered or whatever.

Basically, we want to move our build server onto a new box, but can't because of Star Team and we dont have a support agreement as its costs mega bucks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First issue is: Install Anywhere falls over on Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, ok, I found the answer.

First, renamed the outer setup file as .zip, then use winzip to unpack it. (for both client and server).

Then find the Client and Server setup routines from within the extracted files, then right click on these setup routines and put them into Windows XP compatibility mode.

Found the answer in this.

[Blog](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/davidrobertson/2007/03/05/32718)